# Is it possible to echo what your mic records to the speakers?

Tags: audio, microphone, sound-volume

When I talk on my Blackberry with a headset, it echos what I'm recording back into the headphones. This helps me hear my own voice when I'm talking, so I can regulate my volume.

I'm wondering if it's possible in Mac OS to echo what the mic records back into the speakers and even adjust that volume.

If not, should this be handled at the application layer instead of the OS level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would take a look at Rogue Amobea's application LineIn. LineIn is a free app and can be found at http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/.

From Rogue Amobea's site:

> LineIn is a simple application for OS X to enable the soft playthru of audio from input devices. In simpler terms, you can use LineIn to play sound coming in through a microphone or any other device plugged in to your Sound In port, just as was once available with OS 9's "Play input through output device" option.

Comment: This program is excellent. You load it and press the button that feeds input into just your headphones (not speakers). When you exit the program it stops, and the next time you start it up again it remembers the state it was in last time. Perfect implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It can. If the program you are using allows it. But realistically go into the sound prefs and have it where the input is via a mic, and the output is via the headset. This should do what you need.

Comment: Can you edit the question to describe exactly how to do this? There doesn't seem to be a way in MacOS 10.7.4 Sound setup to make the mic input play through the headphones or speakers.

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long for me to respond real life got involved in aces, but I do have a question. What type of mic do you have?

Comment: It's just the built-in mic of the MacBook Air. You can feed input into the headphones with the MacOS sound settings.